# Clarifying on function calling

Tags: android, c, pointers, structure

I am under learning of Android source code. And I want to know that how the lower level functions are getting calling from application.

While learning in this aspect, now I am in the struggle to understand one file which I have given below:

```
static int open_lights(const struct hw_module_t* module, char const* name,
        struct hw_device_t** device)
{
    int (*set_light)(struct light_device_t* dev,
            struct light_state_t const* state);

    if (0 == strcmp(LIGHT_ID_BACKLIGHT, name)) {
        set_light = set_light_backlight;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(LIGHT_ID_KEYBOARD, name)) {
        set_light = set_light_keyboard;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(LIGHT_ID_BUTTONS, name)) {
        set_light = set_light_buttons;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(LIGHT_ID_BATTERY, name)) {
        set_light = set_light_battery;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(LIGHT_ID_NOTIFICATIONS, name)) {
        set_light = set_light_notification;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(LIGHT_ID_ATTENTION, name)) {
        set_light = set_light_attention;
    }
    else {
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    pthread_once(&g_init, init_globals);

    struct light_device_t *dev = malloc(sizeof(struct light_device_t));
    memset(dev, 0, sizeof(*dev));

    dev->common.tag = HARDWARE_DEVICE_TAG;
    dev->common.version = 0;
    dev->common.module = (struct hw_module_t*)module;
    dev->common.close = (int (*)(struct hw_device_t*))close_lights;
    dev->set_light = set_light;

    *device = (struct hw_device_t*)dev;
    return 0;
}


set_light_backlight(struct light_device_t* dev,
        struct light_state_t const* state)
{
    int err = 0;
    int brightness = rgb_to_brightness(state);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_lock);
    err = write_int(LCD_FILE, brightness);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_lock);

    return err;
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is the meaning of `int (*set_light)(struct light_device_t* dev, struct light_state_t const* state);` this statement?
2. We are just assigning `set_light_backlight` to `set_light`. Then how can `set_light_backlight(struct light_device_t* dev, struct light_state_t const* state)`
   function get called?

Comment: I don't often see 'c' and 'android' tagged in the same question.

Comment: You should at least learn the basics of C and then come back to ask specific questions.

Comment: @Simon ok sir. I knew somewhat in C. But I do not know much about pointer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of int (*set_light)(struct light_device_t*
>   dev,struct light_state_t const* state);

You need to understand what a function pointer is.

A function pointer is a type of pointer to a function. When dereferenced, it will invoke the function it points to and passes the arguments just like a normal function call.

You have a function pointer `set_light` in your program having:

- type `int` as a return type
- And taking two arguments of type `struct light_device_t*` `and struct light_state_t const*`

In your program depending on what **name** contains, you are assigning the function pointer to any **one** of the given functions below at **runtime**.

```
    set_light = set_light_backlight;
```

or

```
    set_light = set_light_keyboard;
```

or

```
    set_light = set_light_buttons;
```

or

```
    set_light = set_light_battery;
```

or

```
    set_light = set_light_notification;
```

or

```
    set_light = set_light_attention;
```

> We are just assigning set_light_backlight to set_light. Then how can
>   set_light_backlight(struct light_device_t* dev, struct light_state_t
>   const* state) function get called?

By calling `set_light()`, with the required parameters, the function `set_light_backlight()`, is called if `set_light()` is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is declaring a function pointer called `set_light`.  The pointer points to a function that returns an int and takes two structs as parameters.
2. You're setting the value of a function pointer.  Someone else will later use the function pointer to call that function, without needing to know what the actual function is (that's the use of a function pointer).  This method is generally called a "callback function".

Answer (score 0):

What you have quoted is a `device-driver` implementation for `lights` in an Android Emulator. Hence, `int (*set_light)(struct light_device_t* dev,  struct light_state_t const* state);` is actually a function pointer declaration. This means `set_light` is a pointer to a function taking a `light_device_t` pointer and `light_state_t` pointer while returning an `int` value.

This is a typical implementation in Android source tree. This implementation is used to have a generic implementation for potentially `n` different cases i.e. based on a case, I may want to call a different function, but the way I set it up and the way I call it, is kept generic through this implementation.

Coming to your next question of where is this invoked. Please refer to this [source file](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_LightsService.cpp). 
In this file, the device is setup [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_LightsService.cpp#73) which will invoke the open method referred by you. Once the setup is complete and `device` is returned, the actual method is invoked in `setLight_native` method as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_LightsService.cpp#125).